# Mutually exclusive checkbox

Tags: itext

I have a PDF form that has has 2 checkboxes with the same name and no export value and they behave mutually exclusive.

When I use:

```
pdfFormFields.SetField("myCheckBox", "1"),
```

the first checkbox is checked.

My question is:

How do I use `pdfFormFields.SetField` to check the second checkbox since it has the same name?

Answer (score 2):

I've taken a look at the form, and it's encrypted, reader-enabled and wrong. There is no such thing as a 'mutually exclusive' checkbox. If such a thing existed, it would be called a 'radio' field.

Apparently, the person who designed the form, didn't know that. I fixed the form by replacing the two widget annotations created for the same checkbox field CheckBox3 (which can not have a different value), by two widget annotations for the single radio field radio (so that one widget corresponds with one value).

You can find the result here: http://itextpdf.org/documents/pos030.pdf

Now you can use either:

```
form.setField("Radio", "0");
```

or

```
form.setField("Radio", "1");
```

You should ask the people of the Canadian government to fix the form accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for replying!  The form is located at: http://www.courts.ca.gov/documents/pos030.pdf  The checboxes in question are 4a and 4b.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Before posting my first answer, I was tempted to edit your question by replacing 'checkbox' by 'radio'. Now I know that the mistake wasn't yours. The mistake was made by the person designing the form.

Comment: Thanks again for the very quick reply, and thanks for solving the problem!  I will study this to get a better understanding of the problem.  I will also notify the creator of the form.  Thanks again for solving my problem, I think I spent about 5 hours on this.

Comment: +1 for answer. @John - If it solved your problem, you should upvote/mark the question as answered...

Comment: @BrunoLowagie how did you change the form? What program did you use? I've got a similar problem with another Canadian government form located at http://www.forms.ssb.gov.on.ca/mbs/ssb/forms/ssbforms.nsf/GetFileAttach/007-11018E~1/%24File/11018E.pdf. The status1 and status2 checkboxes for marital status have a similar issue as the question.

Comment: I used Acrobat, because that was a quick solution. One could use iText to change the field type programmatically, but I'd only write code if it's an operation that has to be repeated over and over again.